# Discrimination of Quantum Ensembles

Tags: quantum-information

Consider the following quantum discrimination problem:

Suppose, there are two sets of states, $P = \{ \rho_i \}$ and $Q = \{\sigma_i\}$. Both Alice and Bob know which states are in each set. We can further assume that, the sets don't have any state in common, i.e, $P\cap Q = \emptyset$.

Alice chooses $N$ states from one of the sets, and gives all of them to Bob (she is allowed to choose one state multiple number of times). Bob doesn't know which set Alice chose, but he is promised that all of the states that he is given belong to the same set (although, all the states might not be the same). Given that, Bob has complete knowledge of the sets $P$ and $Q$, and that he is allowed to perform any generalized measurement on the $N$ states, what is the maximum probability of Bob guessing the correct set? What is the optimal (measurement) strategy that Bob should use ?

*Aside:* 
One might need to make some further assumptions to answer this question. Suppose, one may assume that Alice chooses sets $P$ and $Q$ with probabilities $p$ and $q$, and, that she chooses the state $\rho_i$ given that she chose $P$ with probability $p(i|P)$, etc. I am not sure if the question can be answered if one assumes that Alice doesn't follow an underlying probability distribution.

*Special Case:*
If $P$ and $Q$ each have only **one** element $\rho$ and $\sigma$, and Alice is **equally** likely to chose either set, then the maximum guessing probability is known from the Helstrom Bound of standard Quantum State Discrimination as -
$$
p_{\rm max} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}||\rho^{\otimes N} - \sigma^{\otimes N}||_1
$$
where, $||A||_1$ is the trace-norm of $A$.

*Generalization:*
What would be the answer if $P\cap Q \neq \emptyset$ ?

---

***[Cross-posted on qc.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/33678/55)***